# Wrapping Intent in LabeledIntent for display purposes

Tags: android, android-intent

**The Requirements:**

I have a "share" button in my app.  I have a requirement to share via Facebook.  I need to have the option whether or not the native Facebook app is installed.  Our decision is to send the user to facebook.com to share if the app is not installed.

**The Current State:**

I can detect when the native app is not installed (via the package name), and add additional intents to the chooser.

**The Problem:**

The item the user has to select to share via "Facebook's Website" says, "Browser" and has the Android Browser icon.
The LabeledIntent item does not appear and I get a "No activity found for Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=...}

**The Code (simplified...):**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "check this out");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);
boolean facebookInstalled = false;

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share this link!");
if (!facebookInstalled)
{
    Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + Uri.encode(urlToShare)));
    Intent niceUrlIntent = new LabeledIntent(urlIntent, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), "Facebook's Website", R.drawable.icon);

    // Ideally I would only add niceUrlIntent in the end, but that doesn't add anything to the chooser as-is
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[urlIntent, niceUrlIntent]);
}
context.startActivity(chooser);
```

**The Solution**

The solution as @CommonsWare pointed out, is to use the LabeledIntent to wrap an intent that goes to a new Activity I create, that simply sends a ACTION_VIEW intent to the appropriate Uri.

```
Intent myActivity = new Intent(context, ViewUriActivity.class);
myActivity.putExtra(ViewUriActivity.EXTRA_URI, "http://...");
Intent niceUrlIntent = new LabeledIntent(myActivity, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), "Facebook's Website", R.drawable.icon);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{niceUrlIntent});
```

The ViewUriActivity looks like this:

```
public final class ViewUriActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final String EXTRA_URI = ViewUriActivity.class.getSimpleName() + "EXTRA_URI";

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_URI)));
        startActivity(urlIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding two initial `Intent`s to your chooser?  It looks like you are adding both the labeled and the unlabeled `Intent`.  What happens if you remove `urlIntent` from your array of `Intent`s?

Comment: Push come to shove, create your own activity that you inject into the chooser, that is set with `Theme.NoDisplay` and, in `onCreate()`, calls `startActivity()` to bring up the browser on Facebook, then calls `finish()`. Basically, you use your own activity as a bridge. Ideally, you would not need this, but I have not tried what you are trying to do, so I don't know what may be going wrong (beside Jon O's comment above).

Comment: @JonO, I put both of those in there, so you could see my two attempts.  Removing "urlIntent" from the extra_initial_intents leaves me with no additional intents in the list, and I get the warning I mentioned.  Removing "niceUrlIntent" from the extra_initial_intents leaves me with one additional intent "Browser", which is sadly unacceptable and no warnings in LogCat.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not a huge fan of this solution (mostly on principle) but that is how I got it to work so thank you SO much!  Also as a side-note to anyone, that facebook url above is just for posting a "like" me on facebook type url and is deprecated.

Comment: so nobody ever used `LabeledIntent`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though undocumented, looks like LabeledIntents only work on resolved Intents. So unless the intent already has a specific activity and package defined you will not be able to use it.

This is not surprising since there may be many Activities that might get resolved for one LabeledIntent and your chooserActivity will show all icons and names as same.

So in your case you will have to resolve the acctivity first and then use LabeledIntent. But this might result in user not able to choose browser of their choice.
Use below function to get LabeledIntent from you intent.

```
Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + Uri.encode(urlToShare)));
Intent niceUrlIntent = getLabelintent(urlIntent, "Facebook's Website", R.drawable.icon);
```

And getLabelIntent

```
public LabeledIntent getLabelintent(Intent in, String name, int drawable) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName launchname = in.resolveActivity(pm);
    if (launchname != null) {
        Intent resolved = new Intent();
        resolved.setComponent(launchname);
        resolved.setData(in.getData());
        LabeledIntent niceUrlIntent = new LabeledIntent(resolved,
                getPackageName(), name, drawable);

        return niceUrlIntent;
    }
    return null;
}
```