# How to avoid deep linking loop?

Tags: android, deep-linking

In my android app, I implemented a deep link so that when the user accessed my website, it offers to open it via my mobile app.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:pathPrefix="/myprefix"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="myhost"
                android:pathPrefix="/myprefix"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Some of the features in my website is not implemented in the mobile. That's why I'm opening the browser for the user whenever they want to access that certain feature.

```
    try {
        Uri intentData = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        httpIntent.setDataAndType(intentData, "text/plain"); //NON-NLS
        startActivity(httpIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //print error that user has no browser
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that, after opening the browser, chrome is asking the user whether they want to open the url via chrome or my app. I want to avoid that because I'm the one redirected them to the browser.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057244/how-to-prevent-deep-linking-from-mobile-site-in-android) is the only one I found related to my question, unfortunately it has no answer.

Comment: can't you send a parameter in the link when accessing the page from the application so you know when not to display the pop up?

Comment: @SerbanGorcea unfortunately I can't. I'm hoping to find a solution which I can do inside the app alone.

Comment: You can simply create an Intent chooser by filtering the apps, and therefore removing your own package name.

Comment: @SimonMarquis I didn't know that you could do that. I've only done that for sharing (e.g. sharing links using app). Is this similar to your suggestion? Please elaborate.

Comment: @hehe Check this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390646/wrapping-intent-in-labeledintent-for-display-purposes

Comment: I'm running in to a similar issue with custom chrome tabs.  My app will open the chrome tab, but then I'm immediately deep linked back in to the app and in turn sent back out to the chrome tab resulting in a loop.  Did you get this to work with Simon's approach?

Comment: @Zac unfortunately no. What simon is suggesting is when your own app is the one opening the options, but in this case, chrome is the one showing the options, thus you can't modify it.