# Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER doesn't work with LabeledIntent on Android 12 and below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

What I want to achieve is an Action Chooser that offers me the options to take an image, take a video or select a media from the gallery when an input for file is triggered in a web view. That works fine on Android 13.

For that I have following implementation of `AccompanistWebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser()`:

```
override fun onShowFileChooser(
  webView: WebView?,
  filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
  fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
): Boolean {
  name.value = LocalDateTime.now().toString()
  callback = filePathCallback
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)

  val mimeTypes = arrayOf("image/*", "video/*")
  val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
  contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
  contentSelectionIntent.type = "*/*"
  contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
  contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)

  val takePictureIntent = LabeledIntent(Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), "",
        context.getString(
          R.string.foto
        ), 0)
  takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, context.getPictureUrlForChatStorage(name))
  val takeVideoIntent = LabeledIntent(
       Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE), "",
         context.getString(
            R.string.video
         ), 0)
  takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, context.getVideoUrlForChatStorage(name))

  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent))

  pickMediaLauncher.launch(intent)
  return true
}
```

My `pickMediaLauncher` is implemented like this:

```
val pickMediaLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {...}
```

When the code is executed on a device with Android 12 (or lower), the chooser doesn't show up, and the Gallery is opened immediatly.

When I change the `takePictureIntent` and `takeVideoIntent` to normal Intents like `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` without the Label, then the chooser shows up with the three options I wanted to have.

So the problem is because of the LabeledIntent. But no Android Documentation says that the Action Chooser only works with LabeledIntents on Android 13 and higher.

So what causes this problem then?

Comment: `takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, context.getVideoUrlForChatStorage(name))
` Untried: shouldnt you put that extra on the original intent? And only make a labeled intent out of it when your original intent is build up complete? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390646/wrapping-intent-in-labeledintent-for-display-purposes

Comment: @blackapps putting the extra output on this intent works perfectly. That's not the problem. If I need to make the intents labeled after the original one is built, shouldn't the action chooser then also not work on Android 13?

Comment: I have no idea. Today is the first day i heard about this intent ;-)

Comment: And today i experimented with it a bit and can only confirm your remarks.